# Inject a component property into another component's constructor parameter with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

With Autofac IoC container, say one has the following scenario:

```
public interface IHaveASpecialProperty
{
  SpecialType SpecialProperty { get; }
}

public class HaveASpecialPropertyImpl : IHaveASpecialProperty
{
  // implementation
}

public class SomeComponent
{
  public SomeComponent(SpecialType special)
  {
    _special = special;

    // rest of construction
  }

  private readonly SpecialType _special;

  // implementation: do something with _special
}

// in composition root:

containerBuilder.RegisterType<HaveASpecialPropertyImpl>
  .As<IHaveASpecialProperty>();

containerBuilder.RegisterType<>(SomeComponent);
```

Is there a way to register, within Autofac container, the `HaveASpecialPropertyImpl` type to act as a kind of provider/ factory of `SpecialType` instances?

What I currently have is this *classic* approach:

```
public class SomeComponent
{
  public SomeComponent(IHaveASpecialProperty specialProvider)
  {
    _special = specialProvider.SpecialProperty;

    // rest of construction
  }

  private readonly SpecialType _special;

  // implementation: do something with _special
}
```

The rationale is basically related to the Law of Demeter: `specialProvider` is used only to grab a `SpecialType` instance, which instead is the *actual* dependency needed and used by `SomeComponent`, so it seems reasonable to just inject that `SpecialType` instance, without concerning `SomeComponent` on where that instance comes from.

PS: I've read about [Delegate Factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html), not sure if that's the (only?) way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a delegate :

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IHaveASpecialProperty>().SpecialProperty)
       .As<ISpecialType>();
```

Using this registration, each time you will resolve a `ISpecialType` *Autofac* will resolve a `IHaveASpecialProperty` and return the `SpecialProperty` property value as `ISpecialType`.

Comment: that looks quite nice. I think it never occurred to me to register a delegate with Autofac.